# Mac 64-bit syscall

Tags: c++, macos, system-calls

How to execute a **64-bit** `syscall` on Mac in C++.

I need the below to work:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
  long* addr = (long*) syscall(SYS_mmap, 0, 100, 1 | 2, 2 | 4096, -1, 0);
}
```

The problem is that `addr` below should be 64-bit as it is a pointer, but it truncates the result to 32-bit value.

I compile with:

```
g++ ./mmap.cc -o ./mmap
```

P.S. I know there exists `mmap` function, the above is just an example, I need to get `syscall` function to work.

P.P.S. The problem is that on 64-bit systems `syscall` should return 64-bit value, but in Mac `unistd.h` it is defined as `int`:

```
int  syscall(int, ...);
```

Is that a bug? The `mmap` system call return correctly `void*`:

```
void *  mmap(void *, size_t, int, int, int, off_t) __DARWIN_ALIAS(mmap);
```

How is `mmap` actually implemented?

P.P.P.S.

On Linux it is defined correctly as long:

```
long syscall(long number, ...);
```

Comment: Do you not receive a compiler warning that `syscall()` is deprecated? The function declaration in `unistd.h` is decorated with deprecation attributes which include the statement "syscall(2) is unsupported; please switch to a supported interface." What you're trying to do is explicitly unsupported on macOS. Elsewhere, Apple has explained that the library interfaces (e.g. functions like `mmap()`) are the ABI compatibility interface and direct system calls are not guaranteed to work or remain compatible across OS updates.

Comment: @KenThomases I know all that, do you know how to execute 64-bit `syscall` without resorting to assembly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some searching I did not find a way to execute 64-bit system calls on Mac.

So, I implemented those myself, you [can find the functions here](https://github.com/streamich/libsys/tree/master/syscall).

Also, if you use those functions don't forget to add `0x2000000` Unix system call class shift to your system call numbers:

```
int SYS_write = 4;
int STDOUT = 1;
char* str = "Hello world\n";

syscall3(0x2000000 + SYS_write, STDOUT, str, 12);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `syscall` function is deprecated on OS X as Ken Thomases pointed out.

For your specific example, you should use [`mmap`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) instead of `syscall`. The `mmap` function is not implemented in terms of the `syscall` function but in terms of `__mmap`:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mmap:
    0x7fff643fa69e <+87>:  callq  0x7fff643fe998            ; __mmap
```

which, in turn, does the actual syscall and is probably implemented in assembly:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__mmap:
    0x7fff643fe998 <+0>:  movl   $0x20000c5, %eax          ; imm = 0x20000C5
    0x7fff643fe99d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff643fe9a0 <+8>:  syscall
    0x7fff643fe9a2 <+10>: jae    0x7fff643fe9ac            ; <+20>
```

Comment: As I said, `mmap` was just an example. So, am I correct to say that Mac basically does not have a correct implementation of `syscall` function and I have to implement my own?

Comment: AFAIK yes, you'll have to write your own function if you need a 64-bit return value.